# File "cnn_keras.py", line 51, in train with open("train_images", "rb","wb") as f: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am a newbie and not able to solve this error please can anyone help me out
i am trying to train a model using keras but getting an error i.e. TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
error is in the bold
here is the code :

```
  def train():
    with open("train_images", "rb","wb") as f:
        train_images = np.array(pickle.load(f))
        
    with open("train_labels", "rb") as f:
        train_labels = np.array(pickle.load(f), dtype=np.int32)

    with open("val_images", "rb") as f:
        val_images = np.array(pickle.load(f))
    with open("val_labels", "rb") as f:
        val_labels = np.array(pickle.load(f), dtype=np.int32)
```

here is the output:

```
(mega) G:\sign language\Sign-Language-master>python cnn_keras.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn_keras.py", line 76, in <module>
    train()
  File "cnn_keras.py", line 51, in train
    with open("train_images", "rb","wb") as f:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

can anyone give me some directions to solve this

Comment: What exactly do you expect `open("train_images", "rb","wb")` to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `"wb"` on the second line.